# Difference between jQTouch and jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jqtouch, jquery-mobile

What is the difference between [jQTouch](http://jqtjs.com/) & [jQuery Mobile Framework](http://jquerymobile.com/) ?

Are they related (other than being both based on jQuery) ?

Do they have the same goal ?

**Edit:** jQTouch is now jQT

Answer (score 89, accepted):

jQtouch is optimized for WebKit, jQuery Mobile is looking to support all mobile devices; that is my understanding

some good info here

http://jquerymobile.com/strategy/

and here

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1602169

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Finally I find the different between jQTouch and jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 63):

Additionally to Aaron's answer this is what I've come up with so far:

- jQuery Mobile is an offical and generally more active jQuery project (alpha 4.1 - April 7, 2011) whereas jQTouch, created in 2009 by David Kaneda, has been relatively quiet until release of beta 3 (May 3, 2011)
- jQTouch is a [jQuery plugin](http://blog.jqtouch.com/post/726299094/jqtouch-roadmap) (see "Staying on jQuery" section) while jQuery mobile [is presented as a framework](http://jquerymobile.com/2010/08/announcing-the-jquery-mobile-project/)
- jQTouch is focused on small screen device, from [their blog](http://blog.jqtouch.com/post/726299094/jqtouch-roadmap) :

> Apps developed with jQTouch will certainly run fine on iPads and other tablet devices, but we aren’t going to automagically convert to a more tablet-friendly UI that takes advantage of the additional real estate. If you are in need of a JavaScript library that magically updates your UI for everything from small screens, to tablets, to desktops, check out Sencha Touch.

- I realized that the guy behind jQTouch also worked/works on [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/), which got me even more confused. But he gave some details about the difference between these two on [his blog](http://9-bits.com/post/723711597/jqtouch-and-sencha-touch).

Comment: More info about the difference between Sencha Touch and jQTouch in this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446186/sencha-touch-vs-jqtouch)

Answer (score 6):

For detailed understanding and to know the differences between mobile frameworks,

you can consider the following link.

http://web.bogdanteodoru.com/resources/mobile-framework-comparasion/

Answer (score 2):

As I discuss on my blog post:

http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/04/comparing-jquery-mobile-vs-jqtouch/

I find jQuery Mobile a lot more feature rich and with a lot better cross platform support. JQTouch is very lightweight and great for "form-based" apps that just need navigation. It is missing a lot of the features that users have asked for, and have been turned down, like fixed footers and tabbars.