# JQTouch examples show applications as monolithic one html page creations. Is there a better paradigm for organizing the code?

Tags: javascript, coding-style, jqtouch

I'm not a big fan of the way code is organized in the jqtouch examples I can find. So far, all I've seen are monolithic "index.html" files, which contain all the separate views for the iPhone app as separate divs.

Are there any examples out there of better organized jqtouch code?

I'm not looking for generic advice - I'd like to see specific examples of differently organized code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is usually thought of as a feature of JQTouch, not as a negative "monolithic" style. -- Mobile networks tend to have a large time overhead per http request, so the general idea is to use the one request to download multiple small "pages" (as divs) all at once.

Of course, this paradigm may not fit your use case...

**Added** Re: alternatives: There are lots of mobile frameworks, see a [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917935/which-toolkit-for-iphone-mobile-webapps) or Google. For JQTouch, you can return a response that includes only a single page if you wish to. The reason you're not seeing such examples is because the whole idea of the framework is to make it easy for the developer to return multiple "pages" as a single web server response.

For your server's responses which are a set of mobile pages, the multiple pages-at-a-time trick is the usual approach. For responses which include an infinite scroll page, or which have a lot of dynamic content, you can do Ajax updating of the mobile page, esp if you limit yourself to iPhone and Android browsers.

Overall, the per-request overhead is the big issue for good mobile web app performance. Anytime you can (or probably can) avoid a browser/server round-trip, you should aggressively do so.

Comment: Are there any alternatives, though, or am I stuck with this paradigm?